# SharePoint lists containing other forms/lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, office-365, forms-library

I'll try my best to describe what I want to accomplish!

Basically, I want to create a list that contains many entries of other documents/forms.

*This is for SharePoint Online*

As part of the Change Control process, three persons need to either approve/ or deny any CC request. Let's call these personA, personB and personC. Each of these persons gets a customised form emailed to them for each request where they can approve or deny it. Let's call these formA, formB and formC

So, I want to create a list for each person showing/containing all their respective forms...

List for PersonA:

sharepoint.com/Site/Lists/CRF/formA.aspx?ID=1

sharepoint.com/Site/Lists/CRF/formA.aspx?ID=2

sharepoint.com/Site/Lists/CRF/formA.aspx?ID=3

sharepoint.com/Site/Lists/CRF/formA.aspx?ID=4

sharepoint.com/Site/Lists/CRF/formA.aspx?ID=5

and so on...

List for PersonB:

sharepoint.com/Site/Lists/CRF/formB.aspx?ID=1

sharepoint.com/Site/Lists/CRF/formB.aspx?ID=2

sharepoint.com/Site/Lists/CRF/formB.aspx?ID=3

sharepoint.com/Site/Lists/CRF/formB.aspx?ID=4

sharepoint.com/Site/Lists/CRF/formB.aspx?ID=5

and so on...

List for PersonC:

sharepoint.com/Site/Lists/CRF/formC.aspx?ID=1

sharepoint.com/Site/Lists/CRF/formC.aspx?ID=2

sharepoint.com/Site/Lists/CRF/formC.aspx?ID=3

sharepoint.com/Site/Lists/CRF/formC.aspx?ID=4

sharepoint.com/Site/Lists/CRF/formC.aspx?ID=5

and so on...

I will then assign the appropriate permissions to each list so that only personA can access formA, only personB to access formB etc.

Any help/ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks for reading
Steven

Comment: When you tried to do so, what were the issues that you faced?

Comment: Hi Alok, I have not tried anything yet, I'm not sure how to proceed with creating these lists, hence me reaching out for help here.

Comment: from description of questions it seems like there are two parts of the application: 1: to control application workflows  & 2: to control data access. But question does not much deeper like: Are items getting approved SharePoint items like publishing pages or SharePoint is just a workflow automation tool and after approval is done, someone from team will do something with those artifacts, Why do you need three different forms? Have you already considered Approval Workflows? Question will need to be defined bit more clearly. You may want to start with original issue rather than solution thought.

Comment: Hi Alok.

"Why do you need three different forms?" Because three parties (people) are involved with the approval process.

I have already created an approval workflow and it works great. As soon as a request is submitted, each approver gets sent an email containing the relevant form. 

The problem:

Some people delete these emails, some emails gets automatically deleted/moved by rules etc etc etc whatever. 

What I want: 

I want a list that contains all these forms so that in the event that an email is deleted or misplaced, the user can always go to SharePoint and see these forms.